# C言語で音声ミュート機能を実装したい

Tags: c, windows

C言語でWindowsアプリを趣味で作っているものですが、パソコンをミュートにしたいのですがどのようにしたらよいのか見当がつきません。
ミュートにしたいのはYoutubeの音声です。プログラムを実行すると音声がオフになるようにしたいです。
どなたか対処法を知っている方はいらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: ミュートする対象によって違ってきます。アプリ自身が出す音ですか？ それとも他のアプリが出す音ですか？ もしくはシステム全体ですか？ サウンドにも種類や複数のスピーカーもあります。本気を出すと割と大変です…。

Comment: @nekketsuuu C言語そのものには音声を扱う機能はなく、プラットフォームの明示は重要と考えます。windowsタグは消されるべきではないと考えますがいかがでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri なるほど。個人的には本文に追加したかっただけだったのでタグを付け直しました。（OS のタグは OS 自体の質問でない限りはあまり検索性に影響できていないのではと感じて、自分は消してしまいがちですね……。[windows] でなくて [win32api] でも良いかもしれません（アプリ自身が出す音を消す話なら Win32 API 関係ありませんが）。）

Comment: YouTubeは音を鳴らすわけではありません。あくまで音声データを提供するだけの存在です。YouTubeの音声データを受信し、実際に音を鳴らしているアプリケーション、これを特定しないことにはミュートは実現できません。

Comment: 超絶エスパーをすると特定のブラウザで、任意のURLからの音声再生をブロックするのを自動化したいということだろうか。するともしかして本当に必要なのはこれ？
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mutelinks

Answer (score 6):

コメントにも書きましたが、音声の扱いは難易度が高いです。

- なんとなく全体を制御する
- アプリケーションが自分自身の出す音声を制御する
- 他の特定のアプリケーションの音声を制御する
  （ブラウザーの音声をミュートする等）
- 特定のデバイスの出力を制御する
  （通話中にオーディオ出力をミュートする等）

どのようなことを実現したいかを明示していただく必要があります。参考までにとりあえず雑な方法を提示しておきます。

---

ノートPCやマルチメディアキーボードにはミュートキーを持つものがあります。そのため、Windowsには（該当するキーボードが接続されていなくても）ミュートキーが押された際に行われるべき処理があらかじめ組み込まれています。
この方法はあくまでミュート・ミュート解除がトグルされるのみとなります。現在のミュート状態を把握し、状態に応じた処理を行うとなるとこの方法は使えません。また、あくまでキー操作扱いなので、画面上に音声の状態を表すポップアップが表示されます。

プログラムからミュートキーが押された状態をエミュレートすれば、結果的にミュート・ミュート解除が行われます。具体的には[`SendInput`関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)に[`VK_VOLUME_MUTE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes#VK_VOLUME_MUTE)を渡すことで実現できます。

```
INPUT input = { INPUT_KEYBOARD, { VK_VOLUME_MUTE } };
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof input);
```